# How do I convert C# characters to their hexadecimal code representation

Tags: c#, .net, string

What I need to do is convert a C# character to an escaped unicode string:

So, 'A' - > "\x0041".

Is there a better way to do this than:

```
char ch = 'A';
string strOut = String.Format("\\x{0}", Convert.ToUInt16(ch).ToString("x4"));
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cast and use [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx):

```
char ch = 'A';
string strOut = String.Format(@"\x{0:x4}", (ushort)ch);
```

Comment: I didn't know that was called composite formatting. Thanks! +1