# generate strings for bulk insert of varbinary data from byte[]

Tags: c#, t-sql

I would like to generate the (hex?) string representation of a C# byte[] of some object to be able to bulk imported into a varbinary field. When I use:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(X);
```

I am getting strings that look like this:

```
????N4?V?tw?c??*???9
```

rather than what I see when I do a select statement:

```
0x016C9562F6C8ACE9B25F12788E571C0CA04C2C1F4F7353F849E8199471DB18DC
```

Of course, this might just be a text editor issue.

Any ideas what to use in C# to be able to generate strings for bulk importing the string representation of the data into varbinary fields?

Comment: Do you want to create an insert script with this hex string in it or do you want to do the insert operation out of your C# application?

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what output you expect?

Comment: @Shnugo I want ti create the hex string to run a bulk import via sql.

Comment: Try to quick-watch/ debug your bytearray content and compare with the 0x version without text-encoding it.

Comment: Why varbinary at all? Why *convert* a Unicode string to something else when SQL Server already supports Unicode? If you are trying to store Unicode text, why not use `nvarchar` or `nvarchar(max)`?

Comment: As for the actual problem, what is the input string? And how did you try to store the byets? `?` appears when there is a conversion problem between *codepages*, typically avoided by *not* using codepages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already several answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/369250/28004) on getting HEX from a string, in your case, you mention that your original value is a `Byte[]` and here's some test:

assuming:

```
var s = "helloWorld";
var sB = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
```

you will get `00680065006C006C006F0057006F0072006C0064` using

```
string.Join("", sB.Select(c => String.Format("{0:X4}", Convert.ToInt32(c))));
```

or `68656C6C6F576F726C64` using

```
string.Join("", sB.Select(c => String.Format("{0:X2}", Convert.ToInt32(c))));
```

several [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/724905/28004) let you convert the HEX into String again, if you ever need it...

Comment: I just realized that it is actually just a question to transform the bytes to hex (-: sorry but thanks for your answer.